# Swift Firebase get Data to Class Object

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the following structure (screenshot of Firebase Database):

[image]

In chats I have the id of the chat. There are the users with the child userid and the values of id and name.
At first I look for the chats which a user have and want to get then the details of the chatId (users with their id and name)

I have the following class in Swift:

```
class Chat {
var chatId: String!
var userIds: [String]!
var userNames: [String]!
}
```

I have the following code to get the details, but I get not the userIds or userNames from the chatId:

```
func getChatsFromFirebase() {
    self.ref = Database.database().reference()
    self.ref?.child("users").child(userdefaults.getUserId()).child("chats").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let chat = Chat()
        chat.chatId = snapshot.key
        chat.userIds = []
        chat.userNames = []

        //print(chat.chatId)

        for i in 0..<self.chats.count {
            let usersRef = self.ref.child("chats").child(self.chats[i].chatId).child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

                for userid in value!.allKeys as! [String] {
                    let usersdetailsRef = self.ref.child("chats").child(self.chats[i].chatId).child("users").child(userid).queryOrdered(byChild: "name").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                        //print(value)
                        let id = value?["id"] as? String ?? ""
                        let name = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                        //print( id + ": " + name)
                        chat.userIds.append(id)
                        chat.userNames.append(name)
                    })
                }
            })
        }
        self.chats.append(chat)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

I am very new to the Firebase topic. Can someone help me here? 
Thanks.

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve? Are you looking to fetch usernames from referencing the chat ID

Comment: Yes, I want the usernames from the chatid

Comment: @AakashDave I have the chat id from the Chats, and I want the usernames of the userids given in the chatid

Comment: I have update the answer. If it works, please close the question by accepting and upvoting it. Let me know otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well You need to change your datamodel first. You dont need to store `id` value in , `12345` in this case. you can already fetch the key. Also, in `/users/chats`, you just can just save the chat id as either `chat1 : IBDrbfku887BLIY` or `IBDrbfku887BLIY : true`. You can always fetch them through value or the key respectively.

And in your chat document, you just need to reference the user id, i.e just get them and store them as user1 and user2. You can add more users if your usecase requires more.

Reconfigure your Data Model as follows.

[image]

Now You need 2 Objects Users and Chats as follows :

**Users.swift**

```
class User : NSObject {

        private var _name: String!
        private var _username: String!
        private var _userid: String!
        private var _userRef: DatabaseReference!

        var name: String! {
            get {
                return _name
            } set {
                _name = newValue
            }
        }


        var username : String! {
            get {
                return _username
            } set {
                _username = newValue
            }
        }


        var userid: String! {
            get {
                return _userid
            } set {
                _userid = newValue
            }
        }

        var userRef: DatabaseReference! {
            get {
                return _userRef
            } set {
                _userRef = newValue
            }
        }

        init(userid: String, userData: Dictionary<String, Any>){

            self._userid = userid

            _userRef = Database.database().reference().child(_userid)

            if let username = userData["username"] as? String {
                self._username = username
            }

            if let name = userData["name"] as? String {
                self._name = name
            }

        }

    }
```

**Chats.swift**

```
class Chat : NSObject {

        private var _chatid: String!
        private var _user1: String!
        private var _user2: String!
        private var _chatRef: DatabaseReference!

        var user1: String! {
            get {
                return _user1
            } set {
                _user1 = newValue
            }
        }


        var user2 : String! {
            get {
                return _user2
            } set {
                _user2 = newValue
            }
        }


        var chatid: String! {
            get {
                return _chatid
            } set {
                _chatid = newValue
            }
        }

        var chatRef: DatabaseReference! {
            get {
                return _chatRef
            } set {
                _chatRef = newValue
            }
        }

        init(chatid: String, chatData: Dictionary<String, Any>){

            self._chatid = chatid

            _chatRef = Database.database().reference().child(_chatid)

            if let user = chatData["users"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                if let user1 = user["user1"] as? String {
                    self._user1 = user1
                }
                if let user2 = user["user2"] as? String {
                    self._user2 = user2
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

The major issue/or an overlooked issue here is the type of the data. In the `/users`, you id `12345` will be of type `String`. But when you fetch the same from `/chats`, it returns as `Int`. This downloads the value but never converts it. Always take care while seeding/testing your data.

To fetch the user's credentials just reference that through another query. This is what you can do :

```
var allUsers = [User]()
    var allChats = [Chat]()

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchAllChats()
    }

    func getUser(from userId: String, completion: @escaping (User) -> Void) {

        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            if let datasnap = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                let user = User(userid: userId, userData: datasnap)
                completion(user)
            }
        })
    }

    func fetchAllChats() {
        Database.database().reference().child("chats").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
           allChat.removeAll()
            if let snapshot = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                for snap in snapshot {
                    if let chatd = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                        let chat = Chat(chatid: snap.key, chatData: chatd)
                        self.allChats.append(chat)
                    }
                }
            }
            // collectionview.reloadData() <--------- only if required.
        })
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let chatData = allChats[indexPath.row]
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellId, for: indexPath) as! Cell
        getUser(from: chatData.user1) { user in
            cell.label.text = user.usernme
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will check that and give you feedback

Comment: Sure, Let me know if you didnt get anything. I actually tested this and have posted so I am sure it should work though

Comment: I chave to get the userName by the cellForRowAt. I want to set the label.text to the userName. How I get the userName there? The other part works fine. I get the chats with the userIds

Comment: Can I solve it with a return in the getUser function?

Comment: have you an idea for that?

Comment: @morri_94 Sorry for the delays. It was late night here. I have updated the answer

Comment: and in the method fetchAllChats I want only get the chats of the current userid. The userid I have in user defaults. How I must change the method?

Comment: Well You should have mentioned that point earlier. I would have tweaked the code accordingly. If you alerady have the uid, just add a child after chats in fetchAllChats

Comment: Want to get the chat Ids from the user and get then the chats from the chats node with the ids

Comment: Look, you probably might want to rephrase the question and mention clearly what you exactly want. That'll be the best way to help you.

Comment: I thinked that the „Look for the chats which a user have“ was clear. But sorry if not. I want to get the chats which a user have (chatids in users chats Node) and then get the usernames of these chat. Can you follow me?

Comment: But can I Check in the fetchAllChats if the user1 or user2 of the chat is like the userdefaults userid? And if it is, I append it to allChats? But how I get the user1 or user2 value from the chatData I have there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194196/discussion-between-aakash-dave-and-morri-94).